# Share internet connection on a win 7 pc to other pc connected via router

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, tethering

My situation is this:
I have a modem/router with 2 pc plugged each via lan cable, pretty standard setup.
Unfortunately I find myself often with prolonged connection drop to my ISP. My fallback plan when I absolutely need internet connection is to use USB thethering from my Android device to my PC. Here is the tricky part, sometimes I need to have BOTH pc connected to the internet, but since I have a router I've found myself struggling trying to get it working. Googled around a bit, even found an interesting [answer here on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/479872/windows-7-internet-sharing-how-to-have-simultaneous-internet-access-to-my-clie), but im still in a dead end: the other pc just won't see my other connection available.

Is it because of the android USB thethering and Win 7 can't properly link/bridge/share?Any suggestion? 
Alternatively, is it sensed to directly plug my phone to the router via some adapter like [this one](http://plugable.com/products/usb3-e1000) or similar stuff? 
what would be the better solution?

Comment: why not use wifi tethering?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, should have specified better my specs. I have no wi-fi adapter on my 2 pcs. My router has wi-fi but I don't think he can "get" but only "share" internet connection, am I correct?