# Forward specific IP to localhost

Tags: windows-10, networking, dns, ipconfig

I have this old code that runs tests against an SQL Server with a specific hardcoded IP on my network `192.168.X.Y`, however I want to run such tests against my local server at `127.0.0.1`.

**How can I tell windows that  whenever he receives a request for `192.168.X.Y` it should be forwarded to my localhost?**

I only have windows 10 installed, so its not technically a DNS server, so I cannot forward it. But I assume there should be like a list of `hostname`s as in Linux

Comment: hi, please see if it's helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327952/what-is-the-best-way-to-forward-all-requests-on-a-certain-port-to-another-machin

Answer (score 4):

The hosts file in windows is located at `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`.

If you are using DNS you could map the domain name there to 127.0.0.1.

Alternatively you could configure port forwarding to forward traffic destined for 192.168.x.y on port 3306 to 127.0.0.1 on port 3306 using syntax similar to the below command.

`netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=192.168.x.y listenport=3306 connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=3306`

There is a post here where someone was trying to achieve something similar that you may find useful.

[Windows 10 - NAT - Port forwarding & IP masquerade](https://superuser.com/questions/1088309/windows-10-nat-port-forwarding-ip-masquerade)

Comment: If I use the `netsh` way will it be permant or will it go away on reboot?